# Training a stock market Nerual net, should I replace NaN values with Zero or fill them according to the last trade?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I am working on a Neural Network using Tensorflow on Python with a massive stock market dataset. My features are something like shown below

```
Table 1.0

0   Date               Open      Close     High     Low
1   2019-01-01 09:00   200        201      202      199
2   2019-01-01 09:01   NaN        NaN      NaN      NaN
3   2019-01-01 09:02   200        201      202      199

For the index row 2, I can either make the Nan's 0 and train the neural network OR fill in the values as per the previous slot's close.

Table 2.0

0   Date               Open      Close     High     Low
1   2019-01-01 09:00   200        201      202      199
2   2019-01-01 09:01   201        201      201      201
3   2019-01-01 09:02   200        201      202      199
```

Q1. Will a 0/Nan value be more effective in training the model signifying the low importance of that stock or should I use the previous slot's close as values (Table 2.0) for training the model?

Q2. Is it a compulsion to convert NaN to 0 values for training the model?

Comment: Wouldn’t it make sense to remove the rows without values?

Comment: One thing is clear: don't put 0. It will ruin you dataset as it is a time dependent one and your datas are not close to 0. You should rather try the average between past and future to ensure continuity.

Comment: @SimonF Most likely not, it would mess up the structure of taking measurements at constant intervals. Interpolation is more appropriate.

Comment: @SimonF, I can't do that as I have over 10,000+ columns replicating Open, Close, High, Low for other stocks. I don't have a single row in which all are zerp

Comment: @Alexis, Can you elaborate more on the average between past and the future? Do you think my Table 2.0 would work?

Comment: I do believe that this is a broad question, but definitely I am on board with @Alexis, don't put 0, it will mess up the structure, especially since market data are time series. I wouldn't recommend averaging the value between the close of the previous day and the open of the next day though. This would eliminate the swings you ususally experience between the close on a Friday and the opening on a monday. Keep the data of the previous day, and maybe add a new variable to your table indicating this is a copy of the previous day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should definitely not use 0's in your dataset. a good way of seeing why is to plot the different columns and see the discontinuity that it will produce. If you want to predict variation of the stock as a function of the past, you need to make sure that the value you put in place of the NaN are consistent with the closest values. Providing the previous or next value can be a solution but in case of a large variation, you can see that its getting meaningless. A good option is to do an interpolation between the two closest points: You take the mean of the previous and next value and it gives you an approximation of what the value should be.

What you can do is also add a random number to the data of the previous day to create a random walk.
Let me give you some examples:

- here for the simple interpolation:
  [image]
- here is for an example of a random walk with max distance to previous step set to 5:
  [image]

(i've put the one going to 0 to 190 to avoid a change in scale)

Comment: That makes a lot of sense! Thanks a ton @Alexis for taking the time for a detailed explanation.

Comment: @Neel always a pleasure to help. If it answers your question and you are satisfied with the answer, please accept it to mark the question as solved.